# Why does plugging in a cellular modem create 8 different device files?

Tags: usb, udev, modem, beagleboneblack

I am using a BeagleBone board running Debian.

When I plug in a USB cellular modem, this creates the following files in the `/dev` folder: `ttyACM0`, `ttyACM1`, `ttyACM2`, `ttyACM3`, `ttyModem0`, `ttyModem1`, `ttyModem2` and `ttyModem3`.

I can't find enough information on this. How and why does it create all these files?

Are these files specific to the modem, or general files that are part of the kernel?

dmesg output when I plug in the device :

```
 new high-speed USB device number 4 using musb-hdrc
[  663.611026] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1e2d, 
idProduct=005b
[  663.611046] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, 
SerialNumber=0
[  663.611053] usb 1-1.1: Product: ELSx
[  663.611059] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Cinterion Wireless Modules
[  663.651549] cdc_acm 1-1.1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[  663.659983] cdc_acm 1-1.1:1.2: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
[  663.668360] cdc_acm 1-1.1:1.4: ttyACM2: USB ACM device
[  663.679311] cdc_acm 1-1.1:1.6: ttyACM3: USB ACM device
[  663.689635] cdc_acm 1-1.1:1.8: ttyACM4: USB ACM device
[  663.708738] cdc_ether 1-1.1:1.10 usb0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-musb- 
hdrc.1-1.1, CDC Ethernet Device, fa:96:11:12:13:14
[  663.718331] cdc_ether 1-1.1:1.10 usb0: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[  663.734877] cdc_ether 1-1.1:1.12 usb1: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-musb- 
hdrc.1-1.1, CDC Ethernet Device, fa:96:11:12:13:16
[  663.838982] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
[  663.863935] cdc_ether 1-1.1:1.10 usb0: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[  663.870702] cdc_ether 1-1.1:1.10 usb0: kevent 12 may have been dropped
[  663.914471] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): usb0: link is not ready
```

Comment: It refers to I/O hardware (likely serial outputs) detected on your board. Without any other details, it is impossible to know exactly what they are. Please provide more information so we can provide some answers. You should provide the appropriate part of `dmesg` to see what these devices are.

Comment: @Paradox I've included the appropriate part of dmesg in the question. Thanks

Comment: Could you add what this device is, specifically?

Comment: It's a Zoom 4625 USB cellular modem

Comment: From the `dmesg`, this creates 5 `ttyACM*` devices and 2 `ttyModem*`, not 4 and 4 as in the description. As to why this particular modem creates that many, only the manufacturer knows. Possible reasons: A bug; different interfaces to access different parts of the modem (control vs. data); different interfaces for different bands; or even something else.

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/ttyACMX` is a USB communication device (CDC) of sub-type "abstract control model" (ACM).

As far as I can tell, each `ttyACMX` is an alias to the corresponding `ttyModemX`, which is a GSM modem.

Comment: Why are there four devices tho, and not just one?